# blank folder and zip file is creating while retrieving

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am creating Windows form.I am using folderbrowserdialog,textbox and button.I am retrieving files of specific type from all sub directories and storing them in new folder and than zipping that file.I am wondering what is wrong in my code,it is creating folder,zipfile but no file inside newly created folder and zip file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] extensions = { ".xml",".ddg" };
            string[] d = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            //listBox1.Items.AddRange(d);
            var dir = @"D:\New folderl2221";  // folder location

              if (!Directory.Exists(dir))  // if it doesn't exist, create
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);            
             foreach (var file in d)
              {
                  FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
                  // to remove name collusion
                  if (new FileInfo(dir + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
                      mFile.MoveTo(dir + "\\" + mFile.Name);

              }     
         using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
               zip.AddFile(s, "files");               
                zip.AddDirectory(dir);
                zip.Save(@"D:\Ajax11.zip");
            }
        }
```